# Parsing not producing output expected

Tags: xml, parsing, groovy

I am using Groovy to parse the following file. The portion of code I use is concatenating the person roles at the end of the output even though the person roles are being processed in a loop.

```
def Sample="""
    <tptc:People xmlns:tptc="http://www.metadata.calcum-inc.com/stats/">
        <tptc:Identifier>456-99088</tptc:Identifier>
        <tptc:Name>The Grand Supper</tptc:Name>
        <tptc:Person>
            <tptc:PersonRole>
                <tptc:PersonRoleCode>COMMANDER</tptc:PersonRoleCode>
                <tptc:PersonRoleDescription>
                    IN CHARGE OF   ARMY
                </tptc:PersonRoleDescription>
            </tptc:PersonRole>
            <tptc:PersonRole>
                <tptc:PersonRoleCode>CONDUCTOR</tptc:PersonRoleCode>
                <tptc:PersonRoleDescription>
                    DIRECTS SYMPHONY
                </tptc:PersonRoleDescription>
            </tptc:PersonRole>
            <tptc:PersonName>
                <tptc:PersonFirstName>Jackie</tptc:PersonFirstName>
                <tptc:PersonMiddleName>Wang</tptc:PersonMiddleName>
                <tptc:PersonLastName>Mang</tptc:PersonLastName>
            </tptc:PersonName>
            <tptc:PersonAddress>
                <tptc:PersonAddressLine1Text>String</tptc:PersonAddressLine1Text>
                <tptc:PersonAddressLine2Text>String</tptc:PersonAddressLine2Text>
                <tptc:PersonCityName>String</tptc:PersonCityName>
                <tptc:PersonStateCode>String</tptc:PersonStateCode>
                <tptc:PersonZip5Code>String</tptc:PersonZip5Code>
                <tptc:PersonZip4Code>String</tptc:PersonZip4Code>
            </tptc:PersonAddress>
            <tptc:PersonTelephone>
                <tptc:PersonAreaCode>String</tptc:PersonAreaCode>
                <tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>String</tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>
                <tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>String</tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>
            </tptc:PersonTelephone>
            <tptc:PersonTelephone>
                <tptc:PersonAreaCode>String</tptc:PersonAreaCode>
                <tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>String</tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>
                <tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>String</tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>
            </tptc:PersonTelephone>
        </tptc:Person>
        <tptc:Person>
            <tptc:PersonRole>
                <tptc:PersonRoleCode>First</tptc:PersonRoleCode>
                <tptc:PersonRoleDescription>Best Best</tptc:PersonRoleDescription>
            </tptc:PersonRole>
            <tptc:PersonRole>
                <tptc:PersonRoleCode>None</tptc:PersonRoleCode>
                <tptc:PersonRoleDescription>Nonetity</tptc:PersonRoleDescription>
            </tptc:PersonRole>
            <tptc:PersonName>
                <tptc:PersonFirstName>String</tptc:PersonFirstName>
                <tptc:PersonMiddleName>String</tptc:PersonMiddleName>
                <tptc:PersonLastName>String</tptc:PersonLastName>
            </tptc:PersonName>
            <tptc:PersonAddress>
                <tptc:PersonAddressLine1Text>String</tptc:PersonAddressLine1Text>
                <tptc:PersonAddressLine2Text>String</tptc:PersonAddressLine2Text>
                <tptc:PersonCityName>String</tptc:PersonCityName>
                <tptc:PersonStateCode>String</tptc:PersonStateCode>
                <tptc:PersonZip5Code>String</tptc:PersonZip5Code>
                <tptc:PersonZip4Code>String</tptc:PersonZip4Code>
            </tptc:PersonAddress>
            <tptc:PersonTelephone>
                <tptc:PersonAreaCode>String</tptc:PersonAreaCode>
                <tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>
                    String
                </tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>
                <tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>
                    String
                </tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>
            </tptc:PersonTelephone>
            <tptc:PersonTelephone>
                <tptc:PersonAreaCode>String</tptc:PersonAreaCode>
                <tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>
                    String
                </tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>
                <tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>
                    String
                </tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>
            </tptc:PersonTelephone>
        </tptc:Person>
    </tptc:People>
"""
```

Here is the portion of the code I use:

```
def People = new XmlSlurper().parseText(Sample).
declareNamespace('tptc':'http://www.metadata.calcum-inc.com/stats/')

// Person

People.Person.each
{

    println  it.PersonRole.each{ role->
    println  role.PersonRoleCode
        println  role.PersonRoleDescription
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
COMMANDER
IN CHARGE OF ARMY
CONDUCTOR
DIRECTS SYMPHONY
COMMANDERIN CHARGE OF ARMYCONDUCTORDIRECTS SYMPHONY
First
Best Best
None
  Nonetity
  FirstBest BestNoneNonetity
  Result: COMMANDERIN CHARGE OF ARMYCONDUCTORDIRECTS    SYMPHONYJackieWangMangStringStringStringStringStringStringStringStringStringStringStringStringFirstBest  BestNoneNonetityStringStringStringStringStringStringStringString
 StringStringStringStringStringMANICString
```

It is concatenating all the rest of the output of Person elements. I only want it to print the elements I care about,i.e. the code in the loop. Is there a way to accomplish that? HELP Please!

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because, there isn't anything after your code.

You may below script. what actually this script does is that it collects `role and description` and then finally show the result.

```groovy
def xml="""<tptc:People xmlns:tptc="http://www.metadata.calcum-inc.com/stats/">
    <tptc:Identifier>456-99088</tptc:Identifier>
    <tptc:Name>The Grand Supper</tptc:Name>
     <tptc:Person>
     <tptc:PersonRole>
         <tptc:PersonRoleCode>COMMANDER</tptc:PersonRoleCode>
        <tptc:PersonRoleDescription>
      IN CHARGE OF   ARMY    
    </tptc:PersonRoleDescription>
    </tptc:PersonRole>
    <tptc:PersonRole>
        <tptc:PersonRoleCode>CONDUCTOR</tptc:PersonRoleCode>
        <tptc:PersonRoleDescription>
      DIRECTS SYMPHONY
   </tptc:PersonRoleDescription>
    </tptc:PersonRole>
    <tptc:PersonName>
        <tptc:PersonFirstName>Jackie</tptc:PersonFirstName>
        <tptc:PersonMiddleName>Wang</tptc:PersonMiddleName>
        <tptc:PersonLastName>Mang</tptc:PersonLastName>
    </tptc:PersonName>
    <tptc:PersonAddress>
        <tptc:PersonAddressLine1Text>String</tptc:PersonAddressLine1Text>
        <tptc:PersonAddressLine2Text>String</tptc:PersonAddressLine2Text>
        <tptc:PersonCityName>String</tptc:PersonCityName>
        <tptc:PersonStateCode>String</tptc:PersonStateCode>
        <tptc:PersonZip5Code>String</tptc:PersonZip5Code>
        <tptc:PersonZip4Code>String</tptc:PersonZip4Code>
    </tptc:PersonAddress>
    <tptc:PersonTelephone>
        <tptc:PersonAreaCode>String</tptc:PersonAreaCode>
        <tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>String</tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>
        <tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>String</tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>
    </tptc:PersonTelephone>
    <tptc:PersonTelephone>
        <tptc:PersonAreaCode>String</tptc:PersonAreaCode>
        <tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>String</tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>
        <tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>String</tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>
    </tptc:PersonTelephone>
   </tptc:Person>
   <tptc:Person>
    <tptc:PersonRole>
        <tptc:PersonRoleCode>First</tptc:PersonRoleCode>
        <tptc:PersonRoleDescription>Best Best</tptc:PersonRoleDescription>
    </tptc:PersonRole>
    <tptc:PersonRole>
        <tptc:PersonRoleCode>None</tptc:PersonRoleCode>
        <tptc:PersonRoleDescription>Nonetity</tptc:PersonRoleDescription>
    </tptc:PersonRole>
      <tptc:PersonName>
        <tptc:PersonFirstName>String</tptc:PersonFirstName>
        <tptc:PersonMiddleName>String</tptc:PersonMiddleName>
        <tptc:PersonLastName>String</tptc:PersonLastName>
     </tptc:PersonName>
      <tptc:PersonAddress>
        <tptc:PersonAddressLine1Text>String</tptc:PersonAddressLine1Text>
        <tptc:PersonAddressLine2Text>String</tptc:PersonAddressLine2Text>
        <tptc:PersonCityName>String</tptc:PersonCityName>
        <tptc:PersonStateCode>String</tptc:PersonStateCode>
        <tptc:PersonZip5Code>String</tptc:PersonZip5Code>
        <tptc:PersonZip4Code>String</tptc:PersonZip4Code>
      </tptc:PersonAddress>
       <tptc:PersonTelephone>
        <tptc:PersonAreaCode>String</tptc:PersonAreaCode>
        <tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>
          String
       </tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>
        <tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>String
      </tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>
       </tptc:PersonTelephone>
      <tptc:PersonTelephone>
        <tptc:PersonAreaCode>String</tptc:PersonAreaCode>
        <tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>
             String
      </tptc:PersonTelephoneNumber>
        <tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>
           String
      </tptc:TelephoneTypeCode>
      </tptc:PersonTelephone>
     </tptc:Person>
   </tptc:People>"""

def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def ppl = parsedXml.'**'.findAll{ it.name() == 'Person'}
def result = []
ppl.each { peop ->
  peop.'**'.findAll{ it.name() == 'PersonRole'}.each { role ->
    def detail = []
    detail << role.PersonRoleCode
    detail << role.PersonRoleDescription.text().trim()
    result << detail
  }
}
println result.toString()
```

**Output:**

```
[[COMMANDER, IN CHARGE OF   ARMY], [CONDUCTOR, DIRECTS SYMPHONY], [First, Best Best], [None, Nonetity]]
```

Basically list of data. Since `result` variable has the details in the form of list, you can do whatever you want later.

Comment: Thank you, very much.  Really appreciate the solution!.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. Appreciate if you can vote up if that is helpful.